# Mail Merge - print a specific page depending on merge field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have a mail merge to run that has a front page that needs to go to everyone on the mail merge list and also a follow up page that only needs to go to certain people on the list which can be ascertained by a value in one of the fields.

So print front page, if some value is true print second page (that also contains mail merge fields), if value is false go on to next record.

The second (optional) page needs to retain it's formatting and have the mail merge fields on the page completed too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple matter of using an IF field to conditionally output the second page. For example:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD MyField}= "Y" "Entire second page goes here"}
```

where 'MyField' is your field name, and "Y" is the condition to test.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. Also, the page you want to output cannot contain any double quotes - you would need to replace those with paired single quotes to get the same visual effect.